# Access search query returning PK not value

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've written a search query with multiple parameters, and parameters are entered via an unbound form.  It works except that for one parameter (CostumeInventory.PeriodName) it will return the PK not the value.  All parameters & their values come from join tables, and all are set up the same way--datatypes all match, all the same kind of join--all but this one are showing the values instead of the PK like I want them to.  Any ideas?  Thank you!

Here is my SQL from the query (apologies, I know it's messy, I am just learning so for the most part I'm letting Access write it):

```
SELECT CostumeInventory.SetID, CostumeInventory.InventoryID, 
CostumeInventory.ItemName, CostumeInventory.Description, CostumeInventory.Color, 
CostumeInventory.Size, CostumeInventory.ChestBust, CostumeInventory.Waist, 
CostumeInventory.Hip, CostumeInventory.Inseam, CostumeInventory.Photo1, 
CostumeInventory.Condition, CostumeInventory.RentalRate, 
CostumeInventory.ReplacementValue
FROM CostumeInventory
WHERE (((CostumeInventory.Color) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmItemSearch]![cboColor] & "*") 
AND ((CostumeInventory.GarmentType) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmItemSearch]![cboSelectType] & "*") 
AND ((CostumeInventory.GarmentSubType) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmItemSearch]![cboSubType] & "*") 
AND ((CostumeInventory.PeriodName) Like "*" & [Forms]![frmItemSearch]![cboPeriod] & "*"));
```

Comment: Is PeriodName a lookup field? If so, it is actually storing ID and that is the value used in WHERE clause, not period name. Advise not to build lookup fields in tables so as to avoid this sort of confusion, just build comboboxes on form. LIKE and wildcard on a number value will not work nice. Are the other fields in WHERE clause lookups as well? If these are not lookups then don't include ID field in combobox RowSource.

Comment: @June7 nope, no lookups here!  I originally had them in there, but got rid of them a day or so ago, and this query was built after eliminating them.  On the form to select the parameters (frmItemSearch), the values show up just fine in cboPeriod, but when I run the query, the PK's show up in the column.   This is my RowSource for cboPeriod on the form:

SELECT tblPeriods.PeriodName
FROM tblPeriods;

The values in tbl.Periods.PeriodName are technically numbers--years--BUT the datatype is set to short text not number.

Comment: So you did not build those lookups with Lookup Wizard? Sorry, cannot make sense of issue. Appears to be a design problem, not code. Sometimes weirdness is due to corruption.

Comment: if you have double checked that the control source of [cboPeriod] is blank take a look at the order and how many columns are in the row source. make sure either the bound column matches the column you want to return or refer to the column you want to return in your sql with something like: [cboPeriod].column(correctcolumnnumber)

Comment: @June7  When I first made the tables, yes, I did build lookups with the Lookup Wizard.   However, that was problematic down the line, so I eliminated them from the tables, and changed them on forms as necessary.  This form and query was created after I did that and was never associated with any Lookups.

Comment: Exactly how did you eliminate the lookups from table? Settings from Lookup Wizard can be rather difficult to remove. I had to recreate table and delete old one. Have you run Compact & Repair? @mazoula, query objects cannot refer to combobox or listbox Column property.

Comment: @mazoula That's what I initially thought too.  My table has two columns: the PK (col 1) and the name (col 2).  If I set the bound column to 0 it returns the PK will all the expected results.  If I set the bound column to 1, it will display what I want (the name) but will not return any results.  I'm starting to wonder if something is wrong with my tblPeriods and if I should just delete it and re-build it.  My database only has test dummy data and not much at that so no a huge deal to reconnect things.

Comment: I throught you did not include ID in combobox RowSource?

Comment: @June7 in table design view I went to the Lookup tab and changed the display control to "textbox".  I have not run Compact & Repair, I'll give that a shot.  Thanks!

Comment: @June7 ID is not in the combobox RowSource.  Just the .periodName filed.  Comact & Repair didn't seem to work.  I may have to delete & re-bulld my tblPeriods

Comment: Just changing to textbox in table does not necessarily eliminate lookup relationship, unfortunately. If you look at hidden system table MSysRelationships, you will probably see relationship still listed. Those lookups are nasty, persistent monsters. What happens if you try to delete the field? I have a record in MSysRelationships and I don't know why it is still there. The table might have to rebuild is CostumeInventory because that's where the lookups were built.

Comment: @June7 deleting the field from the Inventory table & re-doing it without Lookups worked!!!  Thank you so much!!!!

Comment: Really! I could not simply delete field, kept telling me had to 'remove relationship from relationships window first', which I couldn't because it didn't show up there. Had to rebuild table. Suggest you not bother designating ID as primary key in tblPeriods, maybe just delete it since it isn't used.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this was a table design issue, not coding.